# Can I do a time based progress in awk?

Tags: awk

I am currently using `awk` scripting to censor the console output and I print one dot for each censored line.

I want to update this code to make it avoid printing more than one dot per minute (or something similar). Obviously that if I do not get any progress (streamed new lines), no update is supposed to happen.

Current version of the code is at https://gist.github.com/ssbarnea/f7b72491af524fa364d9fc328cd43f2a

Note: I know that I could print a newline with "mod 10" or similar in order to limit the output but that approach is not good because the lines are not received with a consistent speed, sometimes I get lots of them, sometimes i get only one or two. Due to this I need to use a timer based approach which would do something like "print newline if the last one was printed more than x seconds ago"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for time functions you can print dots no more frequently than once per minute by simply comparing the time in seconds since the epoch when the current input line is being processed with the time when the previous dot was printed:

```
awk '
function prtDot() {
    currTime = systime()
    if ( (currTime - prevTime) > 60 ) {
        printf "." | "cat>&2"
        prevTime = currTime
    }
}
{ print $0; prtDot() }
END { print "" | "cat>&2" }
'
```

e.g. printing a `.` every 10 seconds within a stream of numbers:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function prtDot() {
    currTime = systime()
    if ( (currTime - prevTime) > 10 ) {
        printf "." | "cat>&2"
        prevTime = currTime
    }
}
{ printf "%s",$0%10 | "cat>&2"; prtDot() }
END { print "" | "cat>&2" }

$ i=0; while (( i < 50 )); do echo $((++i)); sleep 1; done | awk -f tst.awk
1.2345678901.23456789012.3456789012.34567890123.4567890

$ i=0; while (( i < 50 )); do echo $((++i)); sleep 3; done | awk -f tst.awk
1.2345.6789.0123.4567.8901.2345.6789.0123.4567.8901.2345.6789.0
```

the slight difference between the actual digits printed and expected is due to how long other parts of the while loop add to the overall interval between echos and other small imprecisions affecting when the shell loop is printing numbers and consequently when `systime()` is getting called in awk.

Comment: Thank you! On MacOS I had to install gawk. And it seems that now I am able to provide friendly progress lines at https://github.com/pycontribs/powertape/blob/master/vars/sh2.groovy#L106